# Why do we really need information gain to decide the best split in decision tree?

Tags: classification, cart

I was thinking about the paradigm to decide the best split in decision tree, so why do we really need IG? can't we directly use the entropy of the split and decide the best split based on that?

Consider a node at which you are looking for the best split. Now since the Entropy of root node for all the features would have the same entropy, shouldn't entropy of the split suffice?
Are we calculating the IG only to know when to stop splitting the decision tree further?